# Boundaries issues when rotating Text

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I cannot wrap my mind why boundaries of the `Text` do not change and still are as they were before rotation.

I do simply:

```
Text {
     font.family: "Arial"
     color: "#3ba3e4"
     font.pixelSize: 12
     font.letterSpacing: 2
     text: "Vasya was here"
     anchors.left: parent.left
     rotation: -90
}
```

When you align with `parent` it shows gap, I would expect it to be rotated and placed all the way to left side of the `parent`, but now have gap of half of `width` of the previously unrotated element.

Comment: Can you post an image that explains what you expect to happen? Rotation doesn't affect anything besides rotation.

Comment: @Mitch he wants the `Text` all over left side. Which would not be possible with just a rotation like that, as you already said.

Comment: you should instead use the `transform` attribute and give it the Rotation object,`transform: Rotation { origin.x: 25; origin.y: 25; angle: -90}` you should calculate the origin, x and y, depending on the implicitWidth of your text.

Comment: Bounding box of element does no change after rotation, what is not clear here? Imagine:
Text string with bounding rectangle Rect(10,10,100,10), when you rotate it bounding box is still 10,10,100,10 not 10,10,10,100 ? 
I know about origin, manipulation with origin is partial answer.

In order to fix my problem I have to do transformation with origin plus shift to the right x = x - (text.width/2 + text.heigh) in order to have my text where I want it to be. So question is why I have to do this If I have anchors.left: parent.left ?

Answer (score 0):

`rotation` property holds the rotation of the item in degrees clockwise around its `transformOrigin`. `transformOrigin` property holds the origin point around which scale and rotation transform. Nine transform origins are available, as shown in the image below. The default transform origin is `Item.Center`.

[image]

This example rotates an image around its bottom-right corner.

```
Image {
    source: "myimage.png"
    transformOrigin: Item.BottomRight
    rotation: 45
}
```

An approach has already been provided in the comments.

```
Text {
     font.family: "Arial"
     color: "#3ba3e4"
     font.pixelSize: 12
     font.letterSpacing: 2
     text: "Vasya was here"
     transform: Rotation { 
             origin.x: 25; 
             origin.y: 25; 
             angle: -90
         }     
}
```